# Why only water is used to give Arghya to Sun (Surya)?

Tags: puja, surya

I know that offering arghya to Sun (Surya) is a way of saying thank you to Sun (Surya) for provide such enormous amount of light & energy.

My question is why only water is selected to offer arghya to Sun?

Comment: Because the scriptures say water (only) to be used. Btw are u looking for scientific reasons? If u are thn that is not allowed here :) (scientific speculation is off-topic on this site).